# Tips for finding chill PhD programs and advisors to apply to?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I'm in industry now. I'm applying to PhD programs but don't want to be under a lot of stress so that I can have time to slowly think deeply about problems and explore stuff without having pressure to deliver papers and results. And I want to be able to do other things. Any tips on finding universities and advisors that aren't too stressful? In industry it's generally well known what companies work their employees hard (Amazon) and what companies are more chill (Google).

Any university recommendations?

Computer Science, USA

Comment: We do not recommend universities (this would be a shopping question, which would be closed); I suggest you rephrase. "How to find such advisors" might be on-topic.

Comment: That said: I suspect doing a PhD might not be aligned with your goals. Academia's publish-or-perish culture is well known, and that includes grad school. Finally, I am surprised at the suggestion that Google is "more chill"; my (limited) knowledge is that all the FAANG companies require rather extreme effort/hours (but offer many perks in exchange).

Comment: There are definitely good advisors and bad advisors, and a very important step is finding an advisor that you get along with and can work closely with for several years. Having said that, I am quite confident that not one person I know who has gotten a PhD would describe the vibe as chill.

Comment: @cag51 People often joke that googlers work from 12 pm to 2 pm. I'm going to do phd to solve some interesting and tough problems, not get involved in academia's nonsense at publishing every incremental discovery and fooling people into thinking it's super useful.

Comment: @Andrew I went to some open houses and met some folks who said they were chilling.

Comment: Please explain the meaning of "chill" to us.

Comment: Well, I feel like this comment is not going to have any effect, but if you *already* feel that way about academia and you haven't even started grad school, I think you may want to take a step back and think about if there are other areas where you can find interesting problems. I don't mean this in a judgmental way, there legitimately are interesting problems in lots of fields. To me it sounds like you want to commit yourself to a situation you already know you won't like. ... Not to be depressing, but I've heard people say what you are saying now, and I have seen it not work.

Comment: I'm just trying to be helpful. I actually left academia for reasons related to what you are currently saying you don't want. You aren't going to change the system. I'm just trying to save you time in realizing this. But, it's up to you what you want to do.

Comment: @Andrew It's all about working the system, rather than changing it.

Answer (score 7):

You're in the wrong line of business. Graduate programs are populated by those people who were at the top of their class as undergraduates, and professors were at the top of their class of graduate students. These are the people who are inherently competitive and driven in what they do.

That does not mean that every research group and graduate supervisor is toxic. For sure, some research groups are riding their graduate students pretty hard; others have more humane approaches. But in the end, every faculty is evaluated on the number of papers and grants they get published and funded, and that does put inevitable pressure on graduate students as well.

In other words: You will neither be successful nor happy in graduate school (or academia in general) if you are looking for a "chill" environment.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: @JobHunter69 I'm pointing out that there is no answer to your question.

Comment: Consider the worst grad program in the world. It's not going to be populated by people at the top of anything, so your proof is incorrect

Comment: @JobHunter69 Look, smartypants. If you want to argue with everyone here, go somewhere else. You're asking for the opinion of people who have actual experience. You don't have to like it, but the arguments you're bringing forward are just not helpful. Even in the worst graduate program, the people there are still better than the 90% of people who don't go from undergraduate to graduate studies.

Comment: what a joke. a ton of grad students at top schools wouldn't even pass basic industry interviews. Most smart people wouldn't choose to be an overworked slave in academia. You're the one being unhelpful and your arguments are clearly wrong.

Comment: I guess I'm outta here. I've got better things to do in life.

Answer (score 4):

As a thought experiment, let’s pretend for a second that there was at some moment in time a reputable CS grad program in the US that was “chill” like the google environment you’re describing — a place where people can just have a fun, stress free time working on the research they love, knowing that expectations in the program are low enough that they could get out with a PhD even while putting in minimal effort.

Well, what do you think is the next thing that would happen? *Everybody and their cousin would be applying to this program*, that’s what. After all, your preferences aren’t really that unique — there are a lot of people out there who like chilling just like you and dislike stress, just like you. And that includes some very smart, passionate people who actually would turn out to be very hard workers even when you don’t apply a lot of pressure on them.

So, the next thing that would happen after that is, the faculty running the program will find themselves inundated with a veritable bonanza of smart and extremely accomplished applicants to pick from. So, getting into the program will become insanely competitive. Once in the program, students will suddenly find themselves constantly comparing themselves to their other also very accomplished peers, and suddenly feel very motivated and driven to work hard so as to distinguish themselves in such a high-achieving environment. The faculty, realizing they have a great group of grad students on their hands, would realize what a tremendous resource that is to advance the research they are passionate about, so would raise their own expectations and encourage the students to work even harder. Doing anything less than that would just be throwing away the amazing human capital they’ve been put in charge of managing.

And that brings us to precisely where things stand today: grad programs are highly competitive environments where highly motivated, passionate students work extremely hard to meet the very high expectations imposed by the program and the academic discipline they are operating in. Sound familiar?

Well, good luck with your applications anyway, I hope you find what you’re looking for.

Comment: I'm sure your'e an ardent believer of the efficient market hypothesis.

Comment: @JobHunter69 market inefficiencies do exist, and the market for CS PhDs also has small inefficiencies you could exploit by doing your research and optimizing your grad program search for the things that matter most to you. But an inefficiency of the size that I think you’re looking for doesn’t exist. I wish it did — my own grad school experience, in a far away time and place, was actually relatively chill, so it saddens me that US STEM grad programs today don’t make such an experience possible, unless you are exceptionally lucky or brilliant.

Comment: Well there you go. There are inefficiencies but I disagree with you to the degree. Efficient markets occur when knowledge becomes common and everyone is rational. Grad applicants do not rationally optimize their work to time ratio. Most grad students don't even think look for chill programs. They care for prestige of the program, funding, advisor work area, etc. Furthermore, there is no common knowledge about what programs are more or less chill. If it was known which programs were more chill, possibly your effect would be realized.

Comment: And your deduction that the program becomes tougher when more people apply is very debatable. It could instead attract a ton of lazy students thus making the program even more chill. Google is quite prestigious and known to be chill, yet we are not seeing any changes in culture, except at gcp which has always been crap.

Comment: @JobHunter69 yes, anything’s debatable I suppose. Well, good luck, and please report back in a few years about the outcome of your chill PhD search…

Comment: It's always nice to see people who have no inside knowledge of a system debate whether that system works this way or that way. Sometimes the right thing to do is just take the word of people with decades of experience as truth.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the answer you want to hear, but it's the answer that's true: there's just no such thing as a "chill" PhD program. There's lots of variation in the amount of pressure that different programs place on students, but no matter where you go, you've got to work hard. The process of obtaining a PhD is notoriously difficult, and there will, let me repeat, *will*, be occasions where you're clocking in long days and long nights to make your research and writing deadlines. Getting a PhD is exhausting, difficult work and there just is no way around this. If you don't want to put in that level of work ethic, you're just not going to make it in academia.